# prepend Linked Image to menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is how $sticky_menu was created (in case this is an issue):

```
$sticky_menu = $navbar.clone(true).prependTo(".site-container").addClass('sticky-menu');
```

I'm trying to create an image that links to the site's homepage and stick it to the front of a menu tried:

```
$("<img>", {
        src: $('#site-header').data('sticky-header'),
    }).wrap($('</a>', {
        href: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname
    })).prependTo($sticky_menu.find('.jma-positioned'));
```

the image appears in the correct place, but it is not wrapped (no link)... And I suspect that there is a better way to get the href value

Comment: I've tried all the combinations for the a tag <a> <a/> </a> all with single and double quotes. No errors showing in console.

Comment: Im not sure this will work but did you try simple a ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution:

```
$sticky_menu.find('.jma-positioned').prepend($('<a>', {
            href: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host,
            id: 'sticky-home-link'
        }));
        $('#sticky-home-link').prepend($("<img>", {
            src: $('#site-header').data('sticky-header'),
        }));
```

or more directly:

```
$sticky_menu.find('.jma-positioned').prepend($('<a>', {
            href: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host
        }).prepend($("<img>", {
            src: $('#site-header').data('sticky-header'),
        })));
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change a Tag.

```
$('<a>') or $('<a/>')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used the wrong tag so please try below code

```
$('<a />', {
    href: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname
})
```

Instead Of

```
$('</a>', {
    href: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname
})
```

Comment: Can you please provide the jquery version and some more code to check?